# Join two tables and add the result of join to dynamic columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

**Dear,I have the following Tables:**

[image]

[image]

I joined the tables together using **emp_id**

[image]

Here tables and my solution. i think it is not the ideal solution any ideas please.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cdfa3fd85b83ef78812dbfec7ca9d589

Comment: Check out PIVOT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE

```
with mytable as 
(
select t1.* , t2.TICKET,t2.RANK_OF_TICKET from t1 left join t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
) 
select * from mytable 
pivot ( max(TICKET) for RANK_OF_TICKET in ( [1],[2],[3],[4]) ) as pvt
order by emp_id
```

check 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02cd5aeb07976c5dcda88124d69291c4

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would achieve it using pivot

```
select 
  emp_id,
  name, 
  [1] as first_ticket, 
  [2] as [2nd_ticket], 
  [3] as [3rd_ticket], 
  [4] as [4th_ticket], 
  [5] as [5th_ticket]
from (
  select t1.emp_id,
  t1.name,
  t2.TICKET,
  t2.RANK_OF_TICKET 
  from t1 
  left join t2 on t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id) p
PIVOT 
  (
   MIN(TICKET) FOR RANK_OF_TICKET IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
  ) as pvt
ORDER BY emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some conditional aggregation.

```
select 
  x.emp_id
, x.name
, max(first_ticket) as [first_ticket]
, max(second_ticket) as [second_ticket]
, max(third_ticket) as [third_ticket] 
, max(fourth_ticket) as [fourth_ticket] 
, max(fifth_ticket) as [fifth_ticket] 
from (
select 
  t1.*
, case when t2.RANK_OF_TICKET = 1 then t2.TICKET else null end as [first_ticket]
, case when t2.RANK_OF_TICKET = 2 then t2.TICKET else null end as [second_ticket]
, case when t2.RANK_OF_TICKET = 3 then t2.TICKET else null end as [third_ticket]
, case when t2.RANK_OF_TICKET = 4 then t2.TICKET else null end as [fourth_ticket]
, case when t2.RANK_OF_TICKET = 5 then t2.TICKET else null end as [fifth_ticket]
from t1
left join t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
) as x
group by 
  x.emp_id
, x.name
order by x.emp_id
```